# 2 require_once On Same File Create MySQL Connect Issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this index.php :

```
<?php
require_once ('required1.php');
require_once ('required2.php');

--- some mysqli_query here ---
?>
```

what's inside that required1.php is this :

```
<?php
$DbServer = 'localhost';
$DbUser = 'username';
$DbPassword = 'password';
$DbName = 'dbname';
$con = mysqli_connect($DbServer, $DbUser, $DbPassword, $DbName);
?>
```

and this is required2.php :

```
<?php
require_once 'required1.php';

--- some mysqli_query here ---

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

the `mysqli_close($con);` on required2.php makes mysqli_query on index.php failed because the mysql connection already closed by required2.php.

how to make required2.php works independently? I mean, what ever happen on that file (required2.php) leave it there. don't bring anything into other file who calls it, specially the `mysqli_close($con);`

is it possible with require_once? or PHP have another function to make it like that? thanks!

Comment: You could set a global variable in required1.php and make an if statement in required2 if the variable isset

Comment: hi bro, I really appreciate if you can show me some examples. thanks.

Comment: move require_once ('required2.php'); to the bottom of index.php!

Answer (score 0):

Use a different connection in `require2.php` or don't close it. You can also include it at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mysqli_close($con);` in `required2.php` closes the connection, so after any include of `required2.php`, `$con` won't be available.

If you want `required2.php` to be independent, you have to use another database connection, not `$con`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is really no need to close the connection in your included file (there may be very specific exceptions...).

If you want to use your second include independently, you should refactor it to OOP. If it is a class that gets its database connection injected via its constructor (dependency injection), it would only show its name to the rest of your code so things that happen in the class or an object, would not affect the rest of your code.

Of course you still should not close your connection as that object will likely be passed around by reference but using objects / classes instead of procedural code will make it more independent an reusable.

Answer (score -1):

if required2.php has nothing to do with your current script, but all you need to do is to run the script as you mentioned, i feel you can call the file required2.php using file(). this will run both the scripts separately and even if you close connection in required2.php it does not effect the current script.